# How to add nsmutable array into sqlite database table

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, nsmutablearray

How to add  nsmutablearray into the sqlite database table?Can any one help me to code?

Comment: What is the data in your array?? Provide some code snippet , if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **looping Controls** to sort the array and insert each values

**Example:**

```
for(int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < [yourArray count];itemIndex++){

     NSString *myname = [yourArray objectAtIndex:itemIndex];

    //insert myname to database.

}
```

**To retrieve**, you can use the sample below code

```
        if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &dataBase) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select name from syncTable where Crc = %d",crc];         const char *sql = [query UTF8String];
            sqlite3_stmt *statement;
            if (sqlite3_prepare(dataBase, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                char *name;
                unsigned int value;
                while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    name = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);   
                    [yourArray addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name]];

                }
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }
        }
```

Comment: it showing error on `NSString *myname = [yourArrayCount objectAtIndex:itemIndex];
`  yourArraycount..

Comment: while accessing from database can i read directly as a array? or what shud i do..

Comment: while reading the array having only one value at index 0,remaining all returns null value;  @Ramshad

Comment: log the "query" in console, copy and paste and execute in SQLite.. see the result :) also you log the retrieving values in code..

Answer (score 4):

You can use :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < [mutArray count]; i++)
    {
       NSString *string = [mutArray objectAtIndex:i];
       // insert query
       insert into table_name ('string') values(column_name);
    }
```

Comment: anything else without for loop. directly insert array ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of tutorials for using sqlite with iphone. Its not a matter of simulator or device. It will work fine with simulator also.

Create your db structure properly and work based on [this](http://mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/) tutorials.

Or

I'd recommend you to use Core Data if you want you work with databases on iPhone OS.

[This](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/) tutorial should match your app quite well.
Please ask if any more questions.