# How to insert NSMutableArray elements in Sqlite3 in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, nsmutablearray

When I am inserting my array elements into sqlite, it is inserting properly. It takes only the first element in array, for remaining it is showing error while inserting. My code is:

```
NSString *path=[self getDBPath];
sqlite3_stmt *insert_statement = nil;    

if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Array Count is %d",[array count]);
        NSString *name=[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *add=[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"address"];
       
        if (insert_statement == nil) {
            NSString *statement1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tableName (name,address) Values( ?,?)",name,add];
            const char *insertSql = [statement1 UTF8String];
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertSql, -1, &insert_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
                NSLog(@"Error while creating insert statement.");
                insert_statement = nil;
                continue;
            }
            
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 1, [name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 2, [add UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(insert_statement)){
            //NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            NSLog(@"Error while inserting data.");
            insert_statement = nil;
            continue;
        }
        else{}
        
            sqlite3_reset(insert_statement);
            sqlite3_finalize(insert_statement);
            insert_statement = nil;
        }
    }
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Why does it allow only one record?

Comment: I am getting this error ...."Error while inserting data."   ...but the first record of array is added ..it is getting after first record..not inserting remaining data

Comment: Well, that's the message you're printing.  It would be more interesting to know what the `sqlite3_step` is returning.

Answer (score 3):

It's occurred due to finalize statement in loop every time. So it wont let insert other objects after the first object.

Just remove `"sqlite3_finalize(insert_statement);"` from the loop and set `nil` to the insert statement `"insert_statement = nil;"`

After done with loop. Make sure place the `"sqlite3_reset(insert_statement);"` for each object in the loop. It reset the statement and there is no need to set `nil` to the statement in loop.

Try this piece of code, it works for me:

```
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {  

    for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Array Count is %d",[array count]);
        NSString *name=[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *add=[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"address"];
        
        if (insert_statement == nil) {
            NSString *statement1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tableName (name,address) Values( ?,?)",name,add];
            const char *insertSql = [statement1 UTF8String];
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertSql, -1, &insert_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
                NSLog(@"Error while creating insert statement.");
                insert_statement = nil;
                continue;
            }
            
            sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 1, [name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 2, [add UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            
            
            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(insert_statement)){
                //NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                NSLog(@"Error while inserting data.");
                insert_statement = nil;
                continue;
            }
            else{
            
            sqlite3_reset(insert_statement);
            
            
            }
        }
    }
    insert_statement = nil;
    sqlite3_finalize(insert_statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code its works for me

```
      for(int i=0;i<[data count];i++) 
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [data objectAtIndex:i];

            selectSql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO [commentTable] values('%@','%@')",[myDict valueForKey:@"usertype"],[myDict valueForKey:@"userid"]];

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [selectSql cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    ret = YES;
                    NSLog(@"DB SUPPORT - commentTable INSERTED");
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"DB SUPPORT - ERROR commentTable INSERT");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"DB SUPPORT - Sql Preparing Error ( INSERT commentTable)");
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }


        sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: its just a bool variable to check data insert successfully or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
for (int i = 0; i < [mutArray count]; i++)
    {
       NSString *string = [mutArray objectAtIndex:i];
       // insert query
       insert into table_name ('string') values(column_name);
    }
```

Ref : [How to add nsmutable array into sqlite database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563996/how-to-add-nsmutable-array-into-sqlite-database-table)